# activeMQ creates thousands of files in /proc

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

We have two activeMQ brokers running embedded in a spring-boot application, one for MQTT, one for JMS.
There's a camel route that can pass messages between them, since the MQTT is a public endpoint while the JMS broker is only accessible within the network, but for all I can tell currently camel doesn't seem to be participating in causing the problem. Though I'm never quite sure with camel...

The problem is that the application is happily creating tons of files in /proc, until the system limit of open files for a process is reached and the whole thing comes crashing down.

I have already pushed the hard open file limit of Ubuntu to the maximum, but the problem is getting worse the higher the load is.

I can run this command (broker being the user that controlls the application):

```
/usr/bin/lsof | grep broker
```

And what I get back looks something like this (heavily truncated, obviously):

```
ActiveMQ  21482 32629     broker  cwd   unknown                                        /proc/21482/task/32629/cwd 
ActiveMQ  21482 32629     broker  rtd   unknown                                        /proc/21482/task/32629/root 
ActiveMQ  21482 32629     broker  txt   unknown                                        /proc/21482/task/32629/exe 
ActiveMQ  21482 32629     broker NOFD                                                  /proc/21482/task/32629/fd 
ActiveMQ  21482 32632     broker  cwd   unknown                                        /proc/21482/task/32632/cwd 
ActiveMQ  21482 32632     broker  rtd   unknown                                        /proc/21482/task/32632/root 
ActiveMQ  21482 32632     broker  txt   unknown                                        /proc/21482/task/32632/exe 
ActiveMQ  21482 32632     broker NOFD                                                  /proc/21482/task/32632/fd 
ActiveMQ  21482 32650     broker  cwd   unknown                                        /proc/21482/task/32650/cwd 
ActiveMQ  21482 32650     broker  rtd   unknown                                        /proc/21482/task/32650/root 
ActiveMQ  21482 32650     broker  txt   unknown                                        /proc/21482/task/32650/exe 
ActiveMQ  21482 32650     broker NOFD                                                  /proc/21482/task/32650/fd 
MQTTInact 21482 32683     broker  cwd   unknown                                        /proc/21482/task/32683/cwd 
MQTTInact 21482 32683     broker  rtd   unknown                                        /proc/21482/task/32683/root 
MQTTInact 21482 32683     broker  txt   unknown                                        /proc/21482/task/32683/exe 
MQTTInact 21482 32683     broker NOFD                                                  /proc/21482/task/32683/fd
```

I'm not sure what exactly a "task" is in this context, but there's several open files for each of them, and there's thousands of them.
Not really problematic, but still kind of concerning, is that these are by far not the only files created, only the ones currently being held open. THere's hundreds of these task folders, and each contains a whole bag of files:

```
dr-xr-xr-x    7 broker broker 0 Mär 27 12:19 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 2168 broker broker 0 Mär 27 06:37 ../
dr-xr-xr-x    2 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 attr/
-r--------    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 auxv
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 cgroup
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 children
--w-------    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 clear_refs
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 cmdline
-rw-r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 comm
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 cpuset
lrwxrwxrwx    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 12:19 cwd
-r--------    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 environ
lrwxrwxrwx    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 12:19 exe
dr-x------    2 broker broker 0 Mär 27 12:19 fd/
dr-x------    2 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 fdinfo/
-rw-r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 gid_map
-r--------    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 io
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 limits
-rw-r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 loginuid
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 12:19 maps
-rw-------    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 mem
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 mountinfo
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 mounts
dr-xr-xr-x    5 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 net/
dr-x--x--x    2 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 ns/
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 numa_maps
-rw-r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 oom_adj
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 oom_score
-rw-r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 oom_score_adj
-r--------    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 pagemap
-r--------    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 personality
-rw-r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 projid_map
lrwxrwxrwx    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 12:19 root
-rw-r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 sched
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 schedstat
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 sessionid
-rw-r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 setgroups
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 smaps
-r--------    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 stack
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 12:19 stat
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 statm
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 status
-r--------    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 syscall
-rw-r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 uid_map
-r--r--r--    1 broker broker 0 Mär 27 13:42 wchan
```

I don't know what they're used for, or supposed to be used for. All I know is that they get continuously created, and stick around until I reboot the application.

At first I thought this has got something to do with persistence, but I'm not sure about that anymore. True, if the file limit gets reached, the MQTT broker fails to receive new messages with the good old "too many files open" message (though that seems to be because it can't open a socket anymore), but the JMS broker still seems to work without a hitch, and persistence is deactivated for both brokers in the application.

Here's what that configuration looks like:

```
@Bean
fun mqttBroker(mqttProperties: MqttProperties,
               authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
               ssl: SslContext?): BrokerService {
    return BrokerService().apply {
        isPersistent = false
        isAdvisorySupport = false
        brokerName = "mqtt"
        plugins = listOf(WebcamServiceAuthenticationPlugin(authenticationService, mqttProperties.internalPort)).toTypedArray()
        addConnector("tcp://127.0.0.1:${mqttProperties.internalPort}")

        val host = "${mqttProperties.address}:${mqttProperties.port}"

        if (isTlsActive(mqttProperties)) {
            log.info("Starting MQTT connector using TLS")
            sslContext = ssl!!
            addConnector("mqtt+nio+ssl://$host")
        } else {
            log.info("Starting a plain text MQTT connector")
            addConnector("mqtt+nio://$host")
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Component
class JmsBroker(jmsProperties: JmsProperties) {

    private val broker = BrokerService().apply {
        isPersistent = false
        isAdvisorySupport = false
        addConnector("tcp://${jmsProperties.address}:${jmsProperties.port}")
        brokerName = "jms"
    }

    @PostConstruct
    fun start() {
        broker.start()
    }

    @PreDestroy
    fun stop() {
        broker.stop()
    }
}
```

Obviously, I would like my broker to get stable again, but I'm afraid this might be an issue that has always been there, just not made itself noticed because the load wasn't so high. Having no real knowledge of ActiveMQ (it always just worked up until know) I am at a loss as to how to diagnose my issue.
Does anybody know what those files are, what they do, and what might potentially be wrong that leads to so many of them being created and sticking around?

**Additional information:**

Thanks to Justins comment below, I have found out that all these files in the /proc folder are created for running threads. I would honestly have expected to run out of memory long before I run out of available files in such a case, since the machine only has 2 GB RAM.
Also, even assuming that the MQTT-broker, camel and ActiveMQ each create one thread for each message (which they don't, since only maybe a third of the messages go through the MQTT broker), considering our current peak load is well below 10'000 messages per minute (that's kind of the theoretical maximum we *could* get at the moment given our number of clients, but we never actually get them all at once), this should not result in so many threads.

This leaves me to assume that there's a ton of zombie threads lying around here. Which is worrying. I would expect the thread handling of ActiveMQ and Camel to be damn near perfect given how mature they are.
Has anybody ever observed similar behaviour from either of these?

Another thing I just realised it that the overwhelming majority of the threads  are from the JVM itself, not the application (judging by their PIDs). This may be normal given that my activeMQ brokers are running embedded, I have no experience in this area.

**Camel Route**
I was asked to provide the camel route, so here it is:

```
@Component
class BrokerRouteBuilder(camelContext: CamelContext,
                         mqttProperties: MqttProperties,
                         jmsProperties: JmsProperties,
                         private val authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
                         private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper)
    : RouteBuilder() {

    private val jms = "jmsbroker"
    private val mqtt = "mqttbroker"

    init {
        camelContext.addComponent(jms, activeMQComponent("tcp://127.0.0.1:${jmsProperties.port}"))
        camelContext.addComponent(mqtt, activeMQComponent("tcp://127.0.0.1:${mqttProperties.internalPort}"))
        objectMapper.registerModule(JodaModule())
    }

    override fun configure() {

        // CAPTURE

        from("$jms:queue:capture")
                .log("Sending capture command \${body} to user '\${header.user}'")
                .toD("$mqtt:topic:\${header.user}.capture")

        // FOCUS

        from("$jms:queue:focus")
                .log("Sending focus command \${body} to user '\${header.user}'")
                .toD("$mqtt:topic:\${header.user}.focus")

        // REBOOT

        from("$jms:queue:reboot")
                .log("Sending reboot command \${body} to user '\${header.user}'")
                .toD("$mqtt:topic:\${header.user}.reboot")

        // HEATING

        from("$jms:queue:heating")
                .id("heating-command")
                .log("Sending heating command \${body} for user '\${header.user}'")
                .toD("$mqtt:topic:\${header.user}.heating")

        from("$mqtt:topic:*.heating-status")
                .id("heating-status")
                .setHeader("user").message(Companion::extractUserName)
                .log("Received heating status \${body} from \${header.user}")
                .to("$jms:queue:heating-status")

        // SETTINGS

        from("$jms:queue:send-settings")
                .id("send-settings")
                .log("Sending settings to user '\${header.user}'")
                .toD("$mqtt:topic:\${header.user}.settings")

        from("$mqtt:topic:*.request-settings")
                .id("request-settings")
                .setHeader("user").message(Companion::extractUserName)
                .log("Received settings request from \${header.user}")
                .to("$jms:queue:request-settings")

        // PANORAMA SETTINGS

        from("$jms:queue:panorama-settings")
                .id("panorama-settings")
                .log("Sending panorama settings to user '\${header.user}'")
                .toD("$mqtt:topic:\${header.user}.panorama-settings")

        from("$mqtt:topic:*.request-panorama-settings")
                .id("request-panorama-settings")
                .setHeader("user").message(Companion::extractUserName)
                .log("Received panorama settings request from \${header.user}")
                .to("$jms:queue:request-panorama-settings")

        // SCHEDULES

        from("$jms:topic:schedule")
                .id("send-schedule")
                .log("Sending schedules to user '\${header.user}'")
                .toD("$mqtt:topic:\${header.user}.schedule")

        from("$mqtt:topic:*.request-schedule")
                .id("request-schedule")
                .setHeader("user").message(Companion::extractUserName)
                .log("Received schedule request from \${header.user}")
                .to("$jms:queue:request-schedule")

        // HEATING SCHEDULES

        from("$jms:queue:heating-schedule")
                .id("send-heating-schedule")
                .log("Sending heating schedule to user '\${header.user}'")
                .toD("$mqtt:topic:\${header.user}.heating-schedule")

        from("$mqtt:topic:*.request-heating-schedule")
                .id("request-heating-schedule")
                .setHeader("user").message(Companion::extractUserName)
                .log("Received heating schedule request from \${header.user}")
                .to("$jms:queue:request-heating-schedule")

        // HEARTBEAT

        from("$mqtt:topic:*.heartbeat")
                .id("camera-heartbeat")
                .setHeader("user").message(Companion::extractUserName)
                .process().message { message ->
                    val heartbeat = objectMapper.readValue(message.getBody(ByteArray::class.java),
                            HeartbeatMessage::class.java)
                    val user = message.getHeader("user", "", String::class.java)
                    val camera = authenticationService.readCamera(user)
                    heartbeat.camera = camera
                    message.body = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(heartbeat)
                }
                .log(LoggingLevel.TRACE, "Received heartbeat from \${header.user}: \${body}")
                .to("$jms:topic:heartbeat")

        // EVENTS

        from("$mqtt:topic:*.event")
                .id("yellow-event")
                .setHeader("user").message(Companion::extractUserName)
                .process().message { message ->
                    val event = objectMapper.readValue(message.getBody(ByteArray::class.java),
                            YellowEventDto::class.java)
                    // replace username as event source and event-chain with camera id.
                    val camera = authenticationService.readCamera(event.source)
                    message.body = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(event.copy(
                            source = camera, eventChain = event.eventChain.replace(event.source, camera)))
                }
                .log(LoggingLevel.TRACE, "Received event from \${header.user}: \${body}")
                .to("$jms:topic:event")

        // AUTHENTICATION UPDATES

        from("$jms:topic:authentication")
                .process().body(ByteArray::class.java) { body ->
                    val event = objectMapper.readValue<AuthenticationUpdateEvent>(body)
                    authenticationService.onUpdate(event)
                }
        from("direct:request-authentication")
                .to("$jms:queue:request-authentication")

    }

    companion object {
        internal const val destinationHeader = "JMSDestination"
        private val log = logger()

        internal fun extractUserName(message: Message): String {
            val topic = message.getHeader(destinationHeader, "", String::class.java)
            val parts = topic.removePrefix("topic://").split(".")
            return if (parts.size == 2) {
                parts.first()
            } else {
                log.warn("Unexpected topic format '{}'!", topic)
                ""
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I'm instantiating the activeMQComponents manually, as there's two of them and I need to be specific. The main interest seems to be in connection pooling, for which the ActiveMQComponent documentation says the following (note that it explicitly states that this is true by default):

```
    /**
     * Enables or disables whether a PooledConnectionFactory will be used so that when
     * messages are sent to ActiveMQ from outside of a message consuming thread, pooling will be used rather
     * than the default with the Spring {@link JmsTemplate} which will create a new connection, session, producer
     * for each message then close them all down again.
     * <p/>
     * The default value is true. Note that this requires an extra dependency on commons-pool2.
     */
    public void setUsePooledConnection(boolean usePooledConnection) {
        if (getConfiguration() instanceof ActiveMQConfiguration) {
            ((ActiveMQConfiguration)getConfiguration()).setUsePooledConnection(usePooledConnection);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check out the [documentation for proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for an explanation of the "task" entries.

Answer (score 2):

Doug Grove brought me on the track that the problem might not necessarily be the broker itself, but rather the way clients handle their connections, which ultimately proofed to be a fruitful line of inquiry. Though the details are interesting enough to share, I think.

Most of our backend architecture is still running on Spring-Boot 2.0.4, and connecting to the brokers JMS-end via the default JMS listeners and templates.

Lately however a new microservice had been introduced, and it is using Spring-Boot 2.2.4, but pretty much had the JMS connection code copy-pasted from older services.
The trouble is that Spring-Boot 2.2.4 uses another connection factory by default, the [CachingConnectionFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html). Here's the most relevant outtake from the documentation:

> NOTE: This ConnectionFactory requires explicit closing of all Sessions obtained from its shared Connection.

As all the connection code was copied over unchanged, we were not doing this. And this turned out to be the major culprit that was leading to the runaway increase in file descriptors.

It is still a bit odd that the MQTT end of things was the part that could not make any new connections any more, while the JMS end seemed to have no issues, but it is now beyond doubt that this was the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Are these '/proc' entries associated with sockets in the TIME_WAIT state?

```
 netstat -pant | fgrep -i wait
```

Are you using a pooling connection factory for both sending and receiving messages?

```
import org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory;
...
...
public ConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory() {
    JmsPoolConnectionFactory pooledCF = new JmsPoolConnectionFactory();

    pooledCF.setConnectionFactory(myConnectionFactory());
    pooledCF.setMaxConnections(1);

    return pooledCF;
}
```

Comment: After much analysis during the last couple of days, it seems those threads are related to the brokers passing messages between themselves. In any case, with the additional measurements and logging we made until now, it turns out that this can already happen if the broker user has only about 9000 file descriptors open, which is a far cry from the maximum it is allowed to have. Is there anything else that causes the "too many open files" message? I'm searching like mad, but all I find is tutorials on how to raise the descriptor limit...

Comment: To answer your questions specifically, the amount of sockets in wait state seems to hold relatively stable between 100 and 200, sometimes going a bit over or below, but not incrementing out of control. I will add some further logging to get more certainty of that, however. We're not using a ConnectionPool at this time. That's probably one of the next things I'm going to try, thanks.

Comment: As you probably know, the Spring message producer will create a new JMS connection for every message sent.  Depending on how you configure the Spring message listener, it can also create a new connection for every message.  This is what generally leads to running out of file handles under load.

Comment: After looking into this, camel (that transfers the messages from one broker to the other) uses pooled connections by default, so that's fine. The only thing that doesn't are the mqtt clients, but that's not quite so simple. I don't think Paho supports anything like that out of the box...

Comment: Camel does not use pooled connections.  Camel is not involved with connection pooling.  By default, the Spring message listener container will cache a JMS connection and even reuse the message listener.  This is not the case when the message listener is transacted.  The Spring JMS message producer will always create a new JMS connection and session, so using a pooled connection factory is pretty much mandatory if you have any kind of volume and want decent performance.  Can you post you Camel route?